# Controlling order of fields on active admin edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I control the order in which fields appear on an active admin edit page? To customize the View page, I've updated admin/model file with:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Church do
  menu :priority => 2
  scope :inactive
  scope :unregistered
  scope :active
  scope :registered

  show do
    attributes_table :name, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :office_phone,
                 :fax, :email1, :active, :registered
  end
```

However, changing "show" to "edit" or "new" results in a no-method error.

Answer (score 4):

Just change the order of the items in your `attributes_table` and ActiveAdmin will use that order to display.

update: for the edit page...

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Label" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :address1
    # etc
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorens - Thank you for your reply. I'm still missing something here. With the code above, the 'show' form indeed displays the fields in the same order as in the 'attributes_table'. The 'edit' form, however, shows them in a different order.

Comment: @rick apologies, i missed that you were asking about the "edit" page. you need to change the `form do |f| end` where you put the `f.input` in whatever order you want.